# AngularJS WebAPI $http.get Object values are Null

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am relatively new to WebAPI/AngularJS and am having a problem passing an object using $http.get() to a WebAPI controller from an AngularJS controller.

AngularJS Controller Code:

```
$http.get('api/Employee/GetVacancyStatus?emp='+thisData[0])
.then(function (response, success) {
    if (response.data == false){
        alert("cube/office occupied");
    }
    else // continue with employee move
    {
        do some stuff...
    }
}, function (response, error) {
   alert(response);
});
```

Web Api Controller Code:

```
 [System.Web.Http.HttpGet, System.Web.Http.ActionName("GetVacancyStatus")]
    public bool GetVacancyStatus([FromUri] employee emp)
    {
        //return repository.GetVacStatus(moveQuery);
        return false;
    }
```

When I debug the code, the object appears to be populated in the AngularJS Controller (at least from looking at my Chrome developer tools):

[image]

On the other hand, when execution hits the WebAPI controller, it seems that the object is uninitialized and I can't determine what I am doing wrong.

[image]

I do have an $http.put() that seems to be working passing an object like this:

```
 $http.put('api/Employee/PutEmployee', emp)
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: You cannot pass object through URL. You can pass only string.

Comment: You should probably just be passing the id of the employee. Are the other properties necessary for knowing the vacancy status? In addition they are values coming from client-side, so you can't trust them to be correct anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Each property of the employee object you want to pass in has to be a separate query parameter.  You have to do the following in your javascript:

```
$http.get('api/Employee/GetVacancyStatus?Id='+thisData[0].Id + '&fName=' + thisData[0].fName)
```

You don't have to change your controller with this method.